# Using meio upload to programmatically crop photos

Tags: php, cakephp, image-preloader, meio-upload

I want to use CAKE PHP MEIO upload to generate thumbnails of 50 photos programmatically taking from a directory and not by uploading individually.

May Be by calling some meio upload library function.

```
$meio->crop('/path/to/image/')->saveTo('/path/to/target/dir/filename.jpg');
```

Is there any possible way to upload files like this.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageTool](https://github.com/raitisg/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component/blob/master/ImageToolComponent.php) is great for this kind of thing.

Use a combination of cake's `Folder` and `File` utilities to open the directory, loop through the files and apply the necessary resizing.

e.g.:

```
$dir = new Folder('/path/to/my/images');
$files = $dir->find('.*\.jpg'); // find all jpg
foreach($files as $file) {
    $this->ImageTool->resize(...);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Yes, i can do that. But i was trying to do it with MEIO instead of adding another library into my repo.